# MariaDB How to group by 2 or more columns combined

Tags: mariadb

I want to get 1 entry per day per hour from my MariaDB database.

I have a table structured like this (with some more columns):

```
+------------+-----------+
| dayOfMonth | hourOfDay |
+------------+-----------+
```

Let's assume this table is filled like this:

```
+------------+-----------+
| dayOfMonth | hourOfDay |
+------------+-----------+
|         11 |         0 |
|         11 |         0 |
|         11 |         1 |
|         12 |         0 |
|         12 |         0 |
|         12 |         1 |
+------------+-----------+
```

What I want to get is this(in fact all columns) (Every hourOfDay for each dayOfMonth):

```
+------------+-----------+
| dayOfMonth | hourOfDay |
+------------+-----------+
|         11 |         0 |
|         11 |         1 |
|         12 |         0 |
|         12 |         1 |
+------------+-----------+
```

I was able to achieve this with this statement, but it would become way too long if I want to do this for an entire month:

```
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE dayOfMonth = 11 GROUP BY hourOfDay) 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE dayOfMonth = 12 GROUP BY hourOfDay)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group by dayOfMonth, hourOfDay`:

```
SELECT dayOfMonth, hourOfDay 
FROM table 
GROUP BY dayOfMonth, hourOfDay
ORDER BY dayOfMonth, hourOfDay
```

This way you can't select other columns (if they exist), only aggregate on them with `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `AVG()` etc.
Or use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dayOfMonth, hourOfDay 
FROM table 
ORDER BY dayOfMonth, hourOfDay
```

Comment: Could it be that you meant SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY dayOfMonth, hourOfDay ORDER BY dayOfMonth, hourOfDay?

Comment: Yeah thanks, this works. Kinda feel bad now that I searched for this like 1 hour long....

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.  This will transform your initial data into your proposed data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        dayOfMonth, hourOfDay
    FROM tbl;
```

"Every hourOfDay" -- do you want all hours 24 rows per day?  Of so, see the "sequence table" (eg, `seq_0_to_23`) feature in MariaDB.